# Cosmos DB partition key and query design for sequential access

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We would like to store a set of documents in Cosmos DB with a primary key of `EventId`. These records are evenly distributed across a number of customers. Clients need to access the latest records for a subset of customers as new documents are added. The documents are immutable, and need to be stored indefinitely.

*How should we design our partition key and queries to avoid clients all hitting the same partitions and/or high RU usage?*

If we use just `CustomerId` as the partition key, we would eventually run over the **10GB** limit for a logical partition, and if we use `EventId`, then querying becomes inefficient (would result in a cross-partition query, and high RU usage, which we'd like to avoid).

Another idea would be to group documents into blocks. i.e. PartitionKey = `int(EventId / PartitionSize)`. This would result in all clients hitting the latest partition(s), which presumably would result in poor performance and throttling.

If we use a combined PartitionKey of `CustomerId` and `int(EventId / PartitionSize)`, then it's not clear to me how we would avoid a cross-partition query to retrieve the correct set of documents.

**Edit:**

Clarification of a couple of points:

- Clients will access the events by specifying a list of `CustomerId`'s, the last `EventId` they received, and a maximum number of records to retrieve.
- For this reason, the use of `EventId` alone won't perform well, as it will result in a cross partition query (i.e. `WHERE EventId > LastEventId`).
- The system will probably be writing on the order of 1GB a day, in 15 minute increments.
- It's hard to know what the read volume will be, but I'd guess probably moderate, with maybe a few thousand clients polling the API at regular intervals.

Comment: Usually you cannot optimize the partitioning for both reads and writes. Either you make it good for reads or you make it good for writes. A common way to achieve both is to replicate the collection through the change feed to another collection with a different partitioning scheme (or even to a different kind of database).

Comment: It would help to provide some detail on the most common or performance critical queries you expect to run and expected volume. For example the best answer could be different if you expect 80/20 read/write vs 20/80.

Comment: @NoahStahl I've added some more details around expected volumes.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing first, logical partitions size limit has now been increased to 20GB, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#:%7E:text=When%20new%20items%20are%20added,up%20to%2020GB%20of%20data.).

You can use EventID as a partition as well, as you have limit of logical partition's size in GB but you have no limit on amount of logical partitions. So using EventID is fine, you will get a point to point read which is very fast if you query using the [EventID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#using-item-id-as-the-partition-key). Now you mention using this way you will have to do cross-partition queries, can you explain how?

Few things to keep in mind though, Cosmos DB is not really meant for storing this kind of Log based data as it stores everything in SSDs so please calculate how much is your 1 document size and how many in a second would you have to store then how much in a day to how much in a month. You can use TTL to delete from Cosmos when done though and for long term storage store it in Azure BLOB Storage and for fast retrievals use [Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) to query the data in BLOB by using CustomerID and EventID in your search query.

Comment: I've added clarification to the question. Essentially clients will be asking for all recent events, rather than one at a time. Really good point about the use of long term storage - I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: if this is append only data then I would recommend using Azure Data Explorer. It is super-fast and in my view on long term cheaper than Cosmos DB. But even using EventID as a partition key, you can use Azure Search to index your Cosmos DB container and using it is super easy. Construct a query in Azure Search which you will call via REST endpoint with Customer ID from which you can sort by top 10 recent events. But if this is append-only data then makes no sense to use Cosmos or even SQL and Azure Data Explorer makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

**How should we design our partition key and queries to avoid clients all hitting the same partitions and/or high RU usage?**

I faced a similar issue some time back and a PartitionKey with `customerId + datekey` e.g. `cust1_20200920` worked well for me.

I created the date key as `20200920 (YYYYMMDD)`, but you can choose to ignore the date part or even the month `(cust1_202009 /cust1_2020)`, based on your query requirement.

Also, IMO, if there are multiple known PartitionKeys at a query time it's kind of a good thing. For example, if you keep `YYYYMM` as the PartitionKey and want to get data for 4 months, you can run 4 queries in parallel and combine the data. Which is faster if you have many clients and these Partition Keys are distributed among multiple physical partitions.

On a separate note, Cosmos Db has recently introduced an analytical store for the transactional data which can be useful for your use case.
More about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction

Comment: The main issue we ran in to with this approach is this: How do you determine whether a missing block of time for a customer corresponds to no events because the client is up to date, or no events because there were no events for a customer in that block of time? Easiest approach, I guess, would be to add some kind of empty partition marker, but then you need to maintain those markers as new customers are added to the system.

Comment: How are you generating EventId? If you want to use a query like WHERE EventId > LastEventId, event id must be a number. In that case, you can divide eventId with an appropriate factor and use it to create the partition key.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using multiple Cosmos containers as "hot/cold" tiers with different partitioning. We could use two containers:

- `Recent`: all writes and all queries for recent items go here. Partitioned by `CustomerId`.
- `Archive`: all items are copied here for long term storage and access. Partitioned by `CustomerId` + timespan (e.g. partition per calendar month)

The `Recent` container would provide single partition queries by customer. Data growth per partition would be limited either by setting reasonable [TTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live) during creation, or using a separate maintenance job (perhaps Azure Function on timer) to delete items when they are no longer candidates for recent-item queries.

A [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/read-change-feed) processor, implemented by an Azure Function or otherwise, would trigger on each creation in `Recent` and make a copy into `Archive`. This copy would have partition key combining the customer ID and date range as appropriate to limit the partition size.

This scheme should provide efficient recent-item queries from `Recent` and safe long-term storage in `Archive`, with reasonable `Archive` query efficiency given a desired date range. The main downside is two writes for each item (one for each container) -- but that's the tradeoff for efficient polling. Whether this tradeoff is worthwhile is probably best determined by simulating the load and observing performance.